# Escaped string in regexp_replace - Postgresql & PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm importing a csv-file with user-data another person sent me. The file was sent back-and-forth between multiple people, working with different programs on different OS. So some encoding issues occurred and I found no *easy* way to fix it (yes I converted the file to UTF-8 etc).

The data are stored in a postgresql database and I found a way to convert the broken characters.

For example:
â\u0088\u009AÂº = ü
â\u0088\u009AÂ§ = ä
â\u0088\u009Aâ\u0088\u0082 = ö
...

In **psql** I'm using the following statement to convert `â\u0088\u009AÂº` to `ü`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sbl_students WHERE lastname ~* E'.*â\\u0088\\u009AÂº.*';
```

=> 61

```sql
UPDATE sbl_students SET lastname = regexp_replace(lastname, E'â\\u0088\\u009AÂº', 'ü', 'g');
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sbl_students WHERE lastname ~* E'.*â\\u0088\\u009AÂº.*';
```

=> 0

I tried to implement this into a **php** script, but for some reason it doesn't work. **Nothing is replaced and no error occurs.**

```php
$dbh = pg_connect("dbname=iserv user=sbl");
$query = "UPDATE sbl_students SET lastname = regexp_replace(lastname, E'â\\u0088\\u009AÂº', 'ü', 'g');";
pg_query($dbh, $query);
pg_close($dbh);
```

I already tried multiple variations like `regexp_replace(lastname, E'â\u0088\u009AÂº', 'ü', 'g')` or `regexp_replace(lastname, 'â\u0088\u009AÂº', 'ü', 'g')` but non of them worked.

Can anybody help me out? I don't understand why the query works great in psql but doesn't do anything in php.

Thanks!

---

Postgresql 8.4
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze16 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. You have to use **pg_prepare()**:

```
$dbh = pg_connect("dbname=iserv user=sbl");
pg_prepare($dbh, "", "UPDATE sbl_students SET lastname = regexp_replace(lastname, $1, 'ü', 'g');");
pg_execute($dbh, "", array("â\u0088\u009AÂº"));
pg_close($dbh);
```

Still don't understand why :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this?

```
$replacements = array(
    'â\u0088\u009AÂº' => 'ü',
    'â\u0088\u009AÂ§' => 'ä',
    'â\u0088\u009Aâ\u0088\u0082' => 'ö',
    // ...
);

$lastname = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $lastname);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for an SQL-solution.